# windows XP connection to internet problems

Tags: windows-xp, internet-connection

I have a windowx xp sp 3 on my laptop, from several month ago I have a problem, when I connect to internet and after a while, when I try to open a web page, browser message shows that cant connect to page, and after several refresh , I can view that.this problem occur on all sites in that time.
I change my ISP, but problem didnt solve. I check and see if I use dial up, LAN card or wireless , the result is same. in this time all ping request timed out.
I install a fresh copy of windows and for a while every things work fine, and again I have this problem now.I check and see I can't connect to my local network address when this problem occur.
I have F-Prot antivirus and it is up to date.
How can I fix this problem?
Thanks
Mehdi

Comment: I find a file (nssm.exe) and now the problem solved, I have to check this more

Comment: http://www.prevx.com/filenames/X2446079335735271095-X1/NSSM.EXE.html , the problem solved when I removed this malware.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run without the anti-virus.

If this solves the problem, find another anti-virus.

If it doesn't, check if the problem occurs while booting in Safe mode, to determine if the problem is caused by an installed product.